# Number triangle with while loop in c

Tags: c, loops

I'm just starting to learn and this is actually my firts post here, so sorry if it's kind of a silly question.

I need to make a triangle -which width is determined by the user- using loops. I've already managed to do it with the for loop but when I try to rearrange the variables for the while loop, everything becomes chaos.

This is what i have for 'for':

```
main()
{
    int a, i, j, rep;
    do
    {
        printf("Type the width of the triangle \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= a - i; j++)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n Do you want to run the program again? \n 1=Yes \n");
        scanf("%i", &rep);
    }
    while (rep == 1);
}
```

and this is what i tried -and failed- with while:

```
main()
{
    int a, i, j, rep;
    do
    {
        printf("Type the width of the triangle \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        while (i >= 0)
        {
            while (j <= a)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
                j++;
            }
            a--;
            printf("\n");
            i--;
            j = 1;
        }
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            while (j <= a)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
                j++;
            }
            a--;
            printf("\n");
            i--;
            j = 1;
        }
        printf("\n Do you want to run the program again? \n 1=Yes \n");
        scanf("%i", &rep);
    }
    while (rep == 1);
}
```

Comment: Pro tips: (1) format your code properly (2) learn to use your debugger.

Comment: (3) always initialize local variables with values (in your case `int a,i,j,rep;`)

Comment: (4) `main()` ---> `int main (void)`

Comment: Read the definition of the `for` loop. Then, translating a for-loop into a while loop should be a very small problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer `for` part :

```
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= a)
{
    ...
    i++;
}
```

and the inner `for` part :

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
int j = 1;
while (j <= i)
{
    ...
    j++;
}
```

So the whole first loop :

```
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        printf("%i", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

will be transformed to :

```
int i = 1, j;
while (i <= a)
{
    j = 1;
    while (j <= i)
    {
        printf("%i", j);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

---

In a similar manner, the second loop :

```
for (i = 0; i <= a; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= a - i; j++)
    {
        printf("%i", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

will be transformed to :

```
int i = 0, j;
while (i <= a)
{
    j = 1;
    while (j <= a - i)
    {
        printf("%i", j);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from a quick look at your code it seems like your i and j variables are not initiated with a value , in your program it should be 1 or 0 , depend on the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to instanciate the variables because with while they haven't got a value: int j,i = 1;
And then:

```
while (i <= a)
{
    while (j <= i)
    {
        printf("%i", j);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: __they haven't got a value__ they have a value, but most often it's trash

Answer (score 0):

You must translate what for does, so:

1. Init variables before start loops
2. use same conditions for your new `while` loops

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int i;
    int j;
    int rep;
    do
    {
        printf("Type the width of the triangle \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        // init i before start loop
        i=1;
        while (i <= a)
        {
            // init j before start loop
            j = 1;
            while (j <= i)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
                j++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }

        // init i before start loop
        i=0;
        while (i <= a)
        {
            // init j before start loop
            j = 1;
            while (j <= a-i)
            {
                printf("%i", j);
                j++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n Do you want to run the program again? \n 1=Yes \n");
        scanf("%i", &rep);
    }
    while (rep == 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I see I was putting the values in all the wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

In K&R The C Programming Language, the `for` loop is introduced as syntactic sugar for a while loop i.e.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < someValue ; ++i)
//   ^^^^^A  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^B  ^^^C
{
    doSomething(i);
}
```

Is really

```
i = 0; 
//^^^A
while (i < someValue) 
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^B
{
    doSomething(i);
    i++; 
//  ^^^C
}
```

(For the language lawyers, there is a subtle difference, but you don't need to worry about it until you get to `break` and `continue`)

In your program that uses `while` you do not do any initialisation of your loop variables (bits labelled `A` in the code sample above). For example, i and j start out undefined and therefore technically remain undefined throughout the code. If by chance they started out as 0, in your j loops you never reset j back to 0